# How can I join data from both cosmos and sql database?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a requirement where I need to get data from different database i.e. cosmos and sql.
How can I join both the table and get the data?

Below is the data that needs to be fetched. The common column in both is DossierGloabalId which can be use to join both databases tables.

```
Name--SQL
TaxableYear--SQL
Period--COSMOS
DossierType--SQL
VATType--COSMOS
LastUpdated--SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do a join between SQL Server and Cosmos DB, as they are two completely different database engines.

Further: While Cosmos DB's SQL API does have a SQL-based query language, it's not a relational database, and is not compatible with SQL Server.

You'll need to do separate sets of queries: one against Cosmos DB, and one against SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking to perform a relational join on data stored in Azure SQL with data stored in CosmosDB, there is no out-of-the-box support for doing so. You are going to have to query records in Azure SQL, query the corresponding records in CosmosDB, and then join them together in your own application code. There are a bunch of approaches to how you go about this in your own application code, and it's highly dependent on your own application.